# Where are the shortcuts listed under the Places menu stored?

Tags: 12.10, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

How can I edit the contents of the `Places` menu on Ubuntu 12.10?

For example, say I didn't have any videos and wanted to remove the shortcut to `Videos`?

[image: screenshot of places menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the contents by modifying the contents of `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`.

Each entry represents a single entry in the Places menu. If you delete the entry for Videos, which is `file:///home/user/Videos`, it will remove the shortcut to the `Videos` directory.